# Jhipster - production build failure

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

I cannot generate my JHipster application war by running mvnw -Pprod. Here's the error I get in a console:
https://pastebin.com/3wLwy2x4

And my package.json dependencies:

https://pastebin.com/txnATG6M

The solution from:
[Webpack failure during JHipster Prod Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132552/webpack-failure-during-jhipster-prod-package)
doesn't work for me, only the error changes to:

```
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\Programy\Web\softdog2\src\main\webapp\app'
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 2:0-62
[INFO] MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit starts...
[INFO] MergetJsonsWebpackPlugin emit completed...
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 2.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-13T23:29:58+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/532M
```

Also, I get following warnings from yarn:

```
[ERROR] warning " > angular-particle@1.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^4.0.0".
[ERROR] warning " > ng2-page-scroll@4.0.0-beta.12" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@>=4.2.6 <5.0.0".
[ERROR] warning " > ng2-page-scroll@4.0.0-beta.12" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@>=4.2.6 <5.0.0".
[ERROR] warning " > ng2-page-scroll@4.0.0-beta.12" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/platform-browser@>=4.2.6 <5.0.0".
[ERROR] warning " > ng2-page-scroll@4.0.0-beta.12" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/router@>=4.2.6 <5.0.0".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to update Angular libraries versions (in my case from 5.1.0 to 5.1.1).